# How do I move the negative debit values from a column into the credit column and make them positive?

Tags: sql

I have this table in SQL called 'account' that looks like this:

```
Debits  Credits

-22      0

-1      -1

-5       0

 0      -9

-13     -4
```

I want all the values to be positive, but for the account to still make sense at the end. So all the negative values in the Debits column will become positive in the Credits column so that it looks like the table below. How do I go about this? The values in both columns are floats.

```
Debits  Credits

0       22

1       1

0       5

9       0

4       13
```

Thanks!

Comment: Negative debits and credits are contrary to law in some jurisdictions. I'm struggling to imagine in what context this sort of logic is legitimate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data implies that the logic is to swap and negate the debits and credits values:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET
    Credits = -1.0 * Debits,
    Debits = -1.0 * Credits;
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you for the answer Tim, that was very helpful! What if I added an extra row (debits = 200 and credits = 0) to my original table that I wanted to leave unchaged?

Comment: To answer this generally, you would have to provide the rules for when a record does or does not get updated.  For this exact case, add `WHERE Debits <> 200 OR Credits <> 0` to the end of my answer above.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the unary minus operator for a cleaner syntax

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET
    Credits = -Debits,
    Debits = -Credits;
```